# Sub query needed for this condition?

Tags: sql-server

This query is pulling the data correctly in the format I need, but there is a condition that I can't seem to be able to break out...I only want to pull the catalog numbers (sCat) where the text code (stxttype) has a 'NEURPIC' and also a corresponding 'IDURPIC'.  Both conditions must be met.  So stating stxttype IN ('NEURPIC', 'IDURPIC') is not working because it's pulling any catalog number that either or.  Essentially I will need to wipe out the 'NEURPIC' so I need to make sure that the catalog number has both a 'NEURPIC' and 'IDURPIC'.  It's pretty much a duplicate URL that was coded incorrectly which is why I will need to delete.  Thanks in advance as always.

```
DECLARE @nIdPub int

SELECT  @nIdPub = 12439 

SELECT     'TX1.0P'                     AS [Record ID]
, ''                                    AS [Seller ID Qualifier]
, tbCo.nIdIdw                           AS [IDW Private ID]
, CONVERT(smalldatetime,getdate(), 112) AS [Time Stamp]
, 'C'                                   AS [Update Status]
, ISNULL(tbItem.sUpc, '')               AS [UPC]    
, ISNULL(tbItem.sGtin, '')              AS [GTIN]               
, ISNULL(tbItem.sEan, '')               AS [EAN]            
, tbItem.sCat                           AS [Catalog Number]
, tbItemTxt.sTxtType                    AS [Type Code]
, tbItemTxt.sTxt                        AS [Text]
, tbItemTxt.sLang                       AS [Language Code]

FROM        tbItemTxt INNER JOIN
        tbItem ON tbItemTxt.nItemId = tbItem.nItemId INNER JOIN
        tbCo ON tbItem.nIdPub = tbCo.nIdPub

WHERE       tbItem.nIdPub = @nIdPub
and tbItemTxt.sTxtType LIKE '%URPIC%'

ORDER by sCat
```

The expected results should be as follows...

```
sCat        sTxtType
11455        IDURPIC
11455        NEURPIC
22335        IDURPIC
22335        NEURPIC
45678        IDURPIC
45678        NEURPIC
```

Comment: We need to see a few rows of inputs and the expected outputs for those rows.

Comment: Please disregard the 'and tbItemTxt.sTxtType LIKE '%UR%'...

Comment: You also have a SQL injection problem, you're not parameterizing the input the user sends you.

Comment: So the out put should show catalog number twice with the IDURPIC and NEURPIC. see below for example please.

Comment: Don't tell me in the comments; edit your question with the example outputs (in SQL rows, as you'd expect the query to produce). AS well as the example input rows.

Comment: Catalog Number Type Code Text
11455 IDURPIC http://www.ideadigitalcontent.com/files/12236/PIC_11455.jpg
11455 NEURPIC http://www.ideadigitalcontent.com/files/12236/11455.png

Comment: I apologize for that example of the expected results displaying like this.  Basically catalog number is listed twice, which is correct because the catalog number has both a 'IDURPIC' and a 'NEURPIC' tied to it.  I want to pull all catalog numbers that have this circumstance.

Comment: You need to edit that into your question. Not put it in the comments. You can use the code icon to make it display in `<pre>` format.

Comment: I think I have an answer for you, would you please edit your question as @George suggests (showing a few lines of input and a few lines of desired output) so I can see if I really understand the question? You don't need all fields, but definitely include at least sCat and sTxtType.

Comment: Robert Sheahan, I have edited the comments.  Please tell me if you need additional information.  Thanks very much.

Comment: George Stocker, I apologize for the cluster and unclear results that I'm seeking.  Thanks.

Comment: Normally I'd avoid answering in a comment, but the question is on hold and I leave for vacation in a matter of hours, so with my apologies here's what I've got. If the question gets unlocked I'll clean this up and post it as an answer with explanation. Replace your WHERE clause with the following WHERE tbItem.nIdPub = @nIdPub
      AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbItemTxt as NPIC WHERE NPIC.sCat = tbItem.sCat AND NPIC.sTxtType='NEURPIC') 
      AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbItemTxt as IPIC WHERE IPIC.sCat = tbItem.sCat AND IPIC.sTxtType='IDURPIC')

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think what you are looking for is all rows in tbItem that have a sCat that has both a sTxtType='NEURPIC' and sTxtType='IDURPIC'. You can modify your query to return those by replacing your WHERE clause with the following. It basically says does the sCat of this row have a row with a NEURPIC and does it also have a row with a IDURPIC, though neither existing row need be the row currently considered.

```
WHERE tbItem.nIdPub = @nIdPub  
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbItemTxt as NPIC WHERE NPIC.sCat = tbItem.sCat AND NPIC.sTxtType='NEURPIC')  
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbItemTxt as IPIC WHERE IPIC.sCat = tbItem.sCat AND IPIC.sTxtType='IDURPIC')
```

Note that if you have values of sTxtType other than 'IDURPIC' or 'NEURPIC' this will return these as well for any sCat that has both desired values, so you might want to add back in something like your original "stxttype IN ('NEURPIC', 'IDURPIC')"

Comment: Robert Sheahan, perfect...this is exactly what I was looking to for. I added back in the "stxttype IN ('NEURPIC', 'IDURPIC') and worked perfectly.  thanks again and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user3719786, glad I could help, no problem with the confusion, and don't forget to "accept" the answer if it works - people who find this by searching have many posts to sift through and often look for the check mark instead of reading through all the comments to see if a solution is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an inner join with both conditions, like:

```
SELECT    
    t.sTxtType  AS [TYPE Code]  , 
    t.sTxt    AS [TEXT]
FROM        
    tbItem i INNER JOIN
    tbCo c ON 
    i.nIdPub = c.nIdPub INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        nItemId, sTxtType, sTxt
    FROM
        tbItemTxt
    WHERE
        sTxtType = 'IDURPIC') ti ON
    i.nItemId = ti.nItemId  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        nItemId, sTxtType, sTxt
    FROM
        tbItemTxt
    WHERE
        sTxtType = 'NEURPIC') tn ON
    ti.nitemid = tn.nitemid
WHERE       
    i.nIdPub = @nIdPub
```